# pgfplots change fontsize to 1pt nodes near coords

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, fontsize, nodes-near-coords

i want to change the fontsize of the "nodes near coord" and also the y tick labels in a pgfplot to 1pt (no worries, that's just of theoretical interest). I found that

```
\setbeamerfont{MyMiniSize}{size*={1.00}{1.00}}
\setbeamerfont{MyMiniSize2}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries,size={\fontsize{1}{1}}}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\usebeamerfont{MyMiniSize}}}
\pgfplotsset{every node near coord/.append style={font=\usebeamerfont{MyMiniSize}}}
```

should do the thing, but apparently nothing changes. What could be the reason for that?

Here's my MWE (I know, that there are too many coordinates to call it "minimal", but it should explain the need of such a small fontsize)

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\parindent=0mm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme[named =Orange]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{%
  \fontfamily{#1}
  \fontseries{#2}
  \fontshape{#3}
  \selectfont}

\setbeamerfont{MyMiniSize}{
  size*={1.00}{1.00}}

\setbeamerfont{MyMiniSize2}{
  family=\sffamily,
  series=\mdseries,
  size={\fontsize{1}{1}}}

\pgfplotsset{
  every tick label/.append style={
    font=\usebeamerfont{MyMiniSize}}}

\pgfplotsset{
  every node near coord/.append style={
    font=\usebeamerfont{MyMiniSize}}}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.5.1}

\pgfplotsset{
  annot/point format={\%.3f}}

\pgfplotsset{
  annot/js fillColor={["RGB",0.85,0.85,0.85]}}

\hypersetup{bookmarksopen=false}

\begin{document}
\frame{%
  \frametitle{\changefont{phv}{n}{n}Some Title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin                    = 0,
      xmax                    = 20,
      ymin                    = 0,
      ymax                    = 200,
      nodes near coords,
      nodes near coords align = horizontal,
      point meta              = rawx,
      xbar,
      width                   = 9cm,
      height                  = 8.5cm,
      yticklabels             = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H},
      bar width               = 1,
      ytick                   = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198},
      xmajorgrids,
      xtick align             = inside,
      ytick align             = inside,
      tick pos                = left,
      clickable coords]

      \addplot[xbar,fill=blue]
        coordinates{(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(4,4)(5,5)(6,6)(7,7)(8,8)(9,9)(10,10)(11,11)(12,12)(13,13)(14,14)(15,15)(16,16)(17,17)(18,18)(19,19)(20,20)(0,21)(0,22)(0,23)(0,24)(0,25)(0,26)(0,27)(0,28)(0,29)(0,30)(0,31)(0,32)(0,33)(0,34)(0,35)(0,36)(0,37)(0,38)(0,39)(0,40)(0,41)(0,42)(0,43)(0,44)(0,45)(0,46)(0,47)(0,48)(0,49)(0,50)(0,51)(0,52)(0,53)(0,54)(0,55)(0,56)(0,57)(0,58)(0,59)(0,50)(0,61)(0,62)(0,63)(0,64)(0,65)(0,66)(0,67)(0,68)(0,69)(0,60)(0,71)(0,72)(0,73)(0,74)(0,75)(0,76)(0,77)(0,78)(0,79)(0,70)(0,81)(0,82)(0,83)(0,84)(0,85)(0,86)(0,87)(0,88)(0,89)(0,80)(0,91)(0,92)(0,93)(0,94)(0,95)(0,96)(0,97)(0,98)(0,99)(0,100)(0,101)(0,102)(0,103)(0,104)(0,105)(0,106)(0,107)(0,108)(0,109)(0,110)(0,111)(0,112)(0,113)(0,114)(0,115)(0,116)(0,117)(0,118)(0,119)(0,120)(0,131)(0,132)(0,133)(0,134)(0,135)(0,136)(0,137)(0,138)(0,139)(0,140)(0,141)(0,142)(0,143)(0,144)(0,145)(0,146)(0,147)(0,148)(0,149)(0,150)(0,151)(0,152)(0,153)(0,154)(0,155)(0,156)(0,157)(0,158)(0,159)(0,160)(0,161)(0,162)(0,163)(0,164)(0,165)(0,166)(0,167)(0,168)(0,169)(0,170)(0,171)(0,172)(0,173)(0,174)(0,175)(0,176)(0,177)(0,178)(0,179)(0,180)(0,181)(0,182)(0,183)(0,184)(0,185)(0,186)(0,187)(0,188)(0,189)(0,190)(0,191)(0,192)(0,193)(0,194)(0,195)(0,196)(0,197)(0,198)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I really don't want to offend or discourage you from using TeX, but you *really* should read an through the first few chapters of an introduction to LaTeX.  I can tell by the way you've written your document that you're trying to turn it into Word or PowerPoint – this will leave you clinically insane.

Answer (score 4):

Your MWE is far from minimal; I reproduced the situation with a *much* simpler file.

The `.log` file shows everything you need to know:

> ```
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/m/n' in size <1> not available
> (Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 74.
> ```

Numerous warnings like this show up when compiling your MWE. The standard fonts are not available in design sizes this small, so the smallest available one is used.

Using `fix-cm` to tell LaTeX that the font is scalable, we can see that it works fine:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{MyMiniSize}{size*={1.00}{1.00}}
\setbeamerfont{MyMiniSize2}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries,size={\fontsize{1}{1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Banana}

{\usebeamerfont{MyMiniSize} Test\par}

{\usebeamerfont{MyMiniSize2} Test2\par}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

That said: I really can't recommend this, as nobody will even see the numbers. You'll have audience members thinking there are smudges on your beamer's lens, or a fly on the projection screen, or something like that. Here's what it looks like, with a normal-title-size banana for scale:

[image]

And, in the context of the whole slide:

[image]